# Can't Update Contrib Modules via Admin UI

Tags: updating

I'm having a problem with a new Drupal site I'm working on.  I installed Drupal 7.36 and am able to install contributed modules via the admin UI and Drush.  However, I cannot update any contributed modules via the admin UI.  I can update via Drush however.

The error I'm getting is as follows.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /wcbvi/batch?id=9&op=do StatusText:
>   Internal Server Error ResponseText:

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 (32-bit) in VirtualBox with Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9.  I've also installed Curl, Composer, and Drush.

Comment: That is a generic error, can you look into your error_log or even look at "drush ws --tail" and then try UI and see what errors are generated.

Answer (score 1):

No guarantee it will help, but I think it's worth trying (inspired by some of the suggestions in [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1022558#comment-9599331) in [issue nr 1022558](https://www.drupal.org/node/1022558)):

- Increase the php memory limits by editing the following lines in the php.ini file as:

  - max_execution_time = 30 --> 60 ;
  - memory_limit = 32 --> 128, or even 256M ;
- Add the following lines to the end of .htaccess file:

  - php_value auto_append_file none
  - php_value memory_limit 128M

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried all of these yet the issue was not resolved.  However, I've since moved to a 64-bit Ubuntu Server and set it up seemingly in the exact same way and this issue did not reoccur, so it remains a mystery.